# How do you reference the solution folder in .targets?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a custom tool that I run on certain file types using the .targets mechanism in Visual Studio 2015.

Projects exist at many levels, and I want to reference this tool when the code is pulled to ANY drive/folder, including the TFS CI agent.

I tried using a relative path, but because the files are at different levels, it doesn't work for all projects.

I tried using a registry setting and environment variable, but that doesn't bode well for the CI machine which might build in a different folder each time.

Is it possible to get the solution folder of which the project/file is in, then I can use a relative path to the tool directory?

All I can find is these properties, which do not seem to help:
General MSBuild properties:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx

Registry and environment variables:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use all the standard tokens within .targets.
Just use

```
$(SolutionDir)
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Self-service answer: use visual studio's property editing for a vcxproj in preprocessor macros or include paths or such to look at a bunch of available variables. You can usually find what you need in there, by name, or by example, including the one you need here. Better than any documentation.

Comment: I think the thing I might not have explained is that I've got 50 projects in different depths of folder structures in the solution. I am executing a specific tool on certain file types if encountered. I achieve this by importing a .targets file in the csproj files. This centralises the logic, but requires non-project relative paths. However relative to $(SolutionDir) is ok. Do you have a screenshot example of what you're talking about? I've only just taken the leap from VS2010 to VS2015 so may be missing a trick.

Comment: There's no difference in tricks between vs2010 and vs2015. Buuuttttt it looks like you may have to create a c++ project to do this. As I said, vcxproj. Rightclick properties on project, Configuration Properties, Linker, general. Click down arrow on Output File, pick edit. Click macros. Type examples of paths you expect to see, or guess keywords in the search filter box; and you can see what they all evaluate too. Some of those dont make sense in c# but I assume SolutionDir does (I'm not sure, but you said so)